# jsfiddle js panel size is stuck! How do I reset it?

Tags: jsfiddle

Image says it all I think:[image: jsfiddle panel stuck size]

The draggable for resizing the js/html panels is gone and that js pane is too small! The big problem is that this issue persists after restarting my browser, clearing the cache, and deleting cookies. How do I reset this so I can use jsfiddle again?

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's "off-topic," but the jsFiddle guys are pretty good at responding to tweets, @jsfiddle, over on Twitter.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I'll head over there if this goes unanswered for a little while.

Comment: If they respond, from memory it can take a day or so, do consider posting their response as an answer to the question (if they don't themselves answer here).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Please run `Layout.setWindowSizes(null)` from console

https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/493

Comment: This is the kinda crap that and makes me question my love of coding. Thank you.

Comment: This also helps if you've accidentally dragged the vertical middle bar too far to the right, and can't drag it back left.

Comment: Excellent - had the same problem! Worked

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What to do when you actually run `Layout.setWindowSizes(null)`, but the console ends up with showing this the following error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: Layout is not defined(…)`?

Comment: Same here. This solution not working anymore - is there any other workaround?

Comment: Nevermind, it's still working, I just selected wrong context in console.

Comment: @Gargaroz @llamerr In the console, select `top` as the context and it will work. I believe the problem is with running this under the context of adblock.

Comment: @Rohmer, what do you mean by select `top` ?

Comment: @Aurimas go to chrome developer tools console, in the upper left there is a dropdown select menu. Choose `top`.

Comment: while this brings back the drag line, but then immediately jumps back to unusable state, when I try to resize the JS container.

Comment: This solved the issue thanks!Was driving me crazy. Very poor show that this can't be achieved from the UI though.

Comment: There should be a button or something with that function, so annoying.

Comment: True that. I was stuck as well.

Comment: Got thrown off by the 'console' - Didn't realize this was the Browser Console in Chrome or IE. This works like a charm but can it be done as an option under the settings drop down ? Would love to see it there.

Answer (score 1):

As of December 6, 2018, the current answer to this question no longer works due to a rewrite of the JsFiddle site that happened sometime in June/July of 2018.

1. Press F12 to open DevTools (Chrome) or Debugger (Firefox, Edge).
2. Navigate to "Application" in Chrome DevTools, or "Storage in
   Firefox/Edge Debugger.
3. Find "Local Storage".
4. Find www.jsfiddle.net.
5. Delete any entries/keys labeled as `grid_*-split-sizes` (eg.
   `grid_1-split-sizes`, `grid_2-split-sizes`, `grid_3-split-sizes`).
6. Refresh jsfiddle.net webpage.

Source: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1151