# JSFiddle window unable to resize

Tags: html, layout, resize, jsfiddle, window-resize

After extending the JavaScript panel all the way to the right and resizing my browser window, I am now unable to see the results/HTML panels and am unable to drag the bar back into position.

I can resize windows vertically, just not horizontally.

[image]

I have tried, in Chrome:

- Open/Close tab/browser
- Empty Cache
- Disabling/Enabling Cache while in developer mode
- Delete all Cookies
- with console open, Empty Cache and Hard Reload
- Specifically deleting the cookies related to jsfiddle.net via chrome://settings/cookies
- "Manually" setting the 'window_sizes' via this: http://pastebin.com/rBMHfvqV
- Extending the browser window
- Disabled all extensions

---

My current window_sizes:

```
window_sizes = {
    w : [
        "104.46009389671363%",
        "0.4694835680751197%"
    ],
    h : [
        "23.96416573348264%",
        "76.03583426651736%",
        "21.50055991041433%",
        "78.49944008958568%"
    ]
};
```

The windows on jsfiddle appear correctly in Incognito Mode. I also did not go to jsfiddle.net for a week hoping some sort of cookie/mystery meat would expire by then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsfiddle js panel size is stuck! How do I reset it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388509/jsfiddle-js-panel-size-is-stuck-how-do-i-reset-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I wasn't able to find a way to 'set' these window sizes via some command line code.

What I did was go through the page html in developer mode and set the width's manually.

In the "Content" div look for the `<fieldset class = "column left"..>` and `<fieldset class = "column right"..>` and double click on the width or height to set the percentages to something you can actually see.

I did this then reloaded the page and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 11):

You can reset the values of your JSFiddle windows back to default by running the following code from your console:

```
Layout.setWindowSizes(null)
```

Comment: The amount of times, I've used this is embarrassing

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  An odd way to fix this to horizontally stretch the entire window until it's as THIN as possible.  Then hovering over the window, you should be able to adjust the margin.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this bit of JavaScript into your browser's console to clear the cookie:

```js
// Set the cookie date to the previous day.
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (-1*24*60*60*1000));

// Overwrite the cookie's value with an empty string and expire the cookie
document.cookie = "window_sizes=" + "; expires=" + date.toISOString() + "; path=/";
```

After running this script and reloading the page, everything was back to normal for me.